# How do I identify the instruction stored LC-3

Tags: assembly, memory-address, cpu-registers, instruction-set, lc3

I know this is not a programming question but I am struggling to understand how to get the solution to this problem. I'm not sure how this is figured out and I can't find a explained solution. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change in the table is at address `x3406`. That tells us it was a store instruction as no other is capable of writing into memory.

The available store instructions are `ST`, `STI` and `STR`. `ST` uses a 9 bit signed offset from PC which is given as `x3010` in the question and is therefore out of range. `STI` could work but we are not provided with a memory location usable for the indirect address. That leaves `STR` for which the encoding allows for a 6 bit offset so to make the address `x3406` we need a base from `x33E6` to `x3427` which leaves only a single possibility: `R4` for which the offset is `6`.

The new value is `xe373` which must have come from `R2` since again that's the only option.

Comment: (And LC3 doesn't have store-immediate or store with an absolute address embedded in the instruction, because it's a fixed-width ISA.  And it doesn't have stuff like memory-destination ADD; I think the only instruction that writes memory is `str`)

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you I have updated the answer with `ST` and `STI`.